# Deleting 2-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm storing a list of text files inside a vector, and, want to read the contents of the text file into a 2-dimensional array for each iteration:

```
for(unsigned i=0; (i < files.size()); i++)
{
    std::string file = dir + "/" +files[i];
    double** training_vars = new double*;

    training_vars = readFromFile(file);

    delete[] &training_vars;
}
```

I let the function `readFromFile` decide the size of the array and return this array.

The problem that I am having is that each time this runs, I get a `bad_alloc` error. I cannot size the 2D array inside the main either so I'm kind of stuck as to what to do here in order to properly delete the array. Any ideas please?

Comment: This is horrible. Use vectors please.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I cannot use vectors, the function/library that I'm using requires double array. I could possibly use vectors and then covert it to a double

Comment: Use a different library, or store vectors but pass pointers to the vector data in at the last minute. A library is _never_ an excuse for all this manual memory shenanigans, especially two pointers deep.

Comment: Why are you using `delete[]` on **the address of the pointer** (&training_vars) rather than the pointer itself? You should delete the buffer with `delete[] training_vars;`

Comment: And the `new double*` will cause a memory leak, since you're overwriting the pointer afterwards.

Comment: you can use a vector, just pass the .data() to the function that needs the raw array.

Comment: @YvesDubois `delete[] training_vars` would delete the pointer returned from `readFromFile` (not the one allocated via `new` in this code). Th pointer allocated by `new double *` should be deleted via non-array `delete`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Now that I've had a second look at this, you are right. But then the whole allocation of the double pointer is kinda pointless anyways.

Answer (score 2):

**Your program has undefined behavior**, this line is invalid:

```
delete[] &training_vars;
```

Because `&training_vars` was not allocated by a `new []` (note that `training_vars` is simply a pointer to a double, nothing more).

You probably want `readFromFile` to do the allocation for you, possibly by returning a smart pointer, or, better, pass a `vector<>` by const reference to it.

Ideally, always use `std::vector<>` and get rid of C-style arrays, it was designed to avoid situations like this.

---

**Note :**

Your `for` loop has unnecessary parenthesis, and could be replaced by a for-range loop :

```
for(auto& file : files)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really must at least wrap this library with proper "RAII" objects and use modern C++. Something like this will work better for you.

```
for ( auto file : files )
{

    std::shared_ptr< double * > training_vars( readFromFile( file ) );

   // ... the rest of your code that uses training_vars

}
```

And as mentioned elsewhere `delete[] &training_vars;` will probably seg fault. You're passing the address of the stack local "pointer-to pointer-to double" named training_vars to delete. What you want is the address contained in that local variable.

Comment: Why would you use `std::shared_ptr` when the pointer isn't shared?

Comment: We don't know what's going on down in `// ... the rest of your code that uses training_vars`. It might end up shared. Depending on what's happening there, unique_ptr might be more appropriate.